# html - body backgorund image is repeating

Tags: html

As you can see in this page - http://www.white-cell.com/events.htm - 
at the bottom, the background image is repeating because of the long text.
the line that related to this is:

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" background="images/bg_wide.gif">
```

thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use CSS to both specify your background image (`background` is very deprecated) and to turn off the repeating.

Put this in your `head` section:

```
<style type="text/css">
body
 {
     background-image: url(images/bg_wide.gif);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 </style>
```

There is also a property to position the background image (`background-position`).

[more on defining backgrounds at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this style and keep image from repeating:

```
body {
  background:url(images/bg_wide.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

The `no-repeat` will keep image from repeating.